# how to integrate azure function app with vnet network

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless, azure-data-lake, azure-virtual-network

I am creating azure Function that is for copying blob from one container to another container in same Azure Datalake storage account

But, Azure datalake Storage Account is "Enabled for only selected virtual networks and IP addresses" means it is Configured with some network security, so it wont allow in, if we are from different network

In my function App I am using ADLS Connection String for copy function

so, when ever  I execute my Function, it is throwing "SERVICE UNAVAILABLE" error because I am calling ADLS using Function App, here function app don't have any network configurations because it is Serverless.

I'm facing this issue from last 10Days, so please guide me if any suggestions

Thank you

Comment: 1. Make sure you Azure function is on a VNET https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options?tabs=azure-cli#enable-virtual-network-integration Simplest is if you attach it to the same VNET as ADLS 2. Make sure the Azure function VNET and the ADLS VNET have network rules set up so they can talk to each other.

Comment: Yes if I run function locally means with in vdi local host it is working fine but i need to deploy those functions to function App

Comment: VDI / localhost has nothing to do with my explanation. I suggest you read some background on how VNET's work. Have you added a VNET to your function yet?

Comment: No For function app i selected consumption plan

Comment: I guess you need to use service tags then. In your ADLS NSG you need to enable Azure Functions. https://harvestingclouds.com/post/leveraging-service-tags-to-define-better-rules-in-network-security-groups/